# Javascript: inserting a variable as a parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking at getting my "NodeNumber" variable into the parameter of my loadSynchPage function.

my code looks at the name of the page (e.g. page.htm from http://www.example.com/tree/page.htm) and after a series of lines gives a "NodeNumber". I would like the page to work out the NodeNumber and put it into the function when the page loads.
So I'd guess it would look something like this:

```
<BODY onload="loadSynchPage(NodeNumber);">
```

I have got my code to output the NodeNumber using a button with onlick.
I have also got the loadSynchPage(linkID) function, to work using a button with onclick where I enter the number myself. button and have also got a variable which I predefine to work; but I can't get it to read my "NodeNumber" and I have spent 2 days trying to figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function variables() {
//Getting the page's name from the URL
PageName = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
document.getElementById("PageName").innerHTML = PageName;

//Converting the page name into a string
PageNameString = String(PageName);
document.getElementById("PageNameString").innerHTML = PageNameString;

//Converting the string of the page name, into it's length
PageLength = PageNameString.length;
document.getElementById("PageLength").innerHTML = PageLength;

//Setting the DemoFramesetNodes.js as a variable (Copy and Paste in - needs to have no " and be on one line)
TextFromDemoFramesetNodesJS = "foldersTree = gFld(<i>Page 1 Title</i>, page1.htm)//000foldersTree.treeID = Framesetaux1 = insFld(foldersTree, gFld(Page 2 Title, page 2.htm)) //001insDoc(aux1, gLnk(R, Page 3 Title, Page3.htm)) //002aux1 = insFld(foldersTree, gFld(Page 4 Title, Page4.htm)) //003insDoc(aux1, gLnk(R, Page 5 Title, Page5.htm)) //004";
//Need to set the difference BETWEEN the "m" in htm and the start of the number
//e.g. page2.htm)) //001
CharacterDifference = "5";
document.getElementById("CharacterDifference").innerHTML = CharacterDifference;

//Need to find the location of the page's name from the DemoFramsetNodes
PageNameLocation = TextFromDemoFramesetNodesJS.lastIndexOf(PageNameString);
document.getElementById("PageNameLocation").innerHTML = PageNameLocation;

//Need to convert all variables to be added into numbers
PageNameLocationNumber = Number(PageNameLocation);
PageLengthNumber = Number(PageLength);
CharacterDifferenceNumber = Number(CharacterDifference);
document.getElementById("CharacterDifferenceNumber").innerHTML = CharacterDifferenceNumber;

//Add the variables to give us the start location of the Node Number
NodeNumberStart = PageNameLocationNumber + PageLengthNumber + CharacterDifferenceNumber;
document.getElementById("NodeNumberStart").innerHTML = NodeNumberStart;

//Add the variables to give us the end location of the Node Number
NodeNumberEnd = PageNameLocationNumber + PageLengthNumber + CharacterDifferenceNumber + 3;
document.getElementById("NodeNumberEnd").innerHTML = NodeNumberEnd;

//this gives us the Node Number that we want
NodeNumber = TextFromDemoFramesetNodesJS.substring(NodeNumberStart, NodeNumberEnd);
document.getElementById("NodeNumber").innerHTML = NodeNumber;

}
 var avar=Number(window.NodeNumber);

 //window.NodeNumber;

function loadSynchPage(linkID) {
var folderObj;
docObj = parent.treeframe.findObj(linkID);
docObj.forceOpeningOfAncestorFolders();
parent.treeframe.HightlightNode(linkID,docObj.link,'basefrm');
if (typeof parent.treeframe.document.body != "undefined") // To handle scrolling not working with NS4
parent.treeframe.document.body.scrollTop=docObj.navObj.offsetTop

}


//myvar=Number(NodeNumber);


// function loadnode(){
// document.getElementById('loadSynchPage').onclick=function(){loadSynchPage(myvar);};  

//   var myvar=15;
//function init(){
//    document.getElementById('EditBanner').onclick=function(){EditBanner(myvar);};
// }
</script>
</head>

<BODY>

<button onclick="javascript:settingvariables();">Page Highlight1</button>
<button onclick="javascript:loadSynchPage(avar);">Page Highlight2</button>


Page Name: <p id="PageName"></p>
Page Name String: <p id="PageNameString"></p>
Page Length: <p id="PageLength"></p>
Character Difference: <p id="CharacterDifference"></p>
Page Name Location: <p id="PageNameLocation"></p>
Character Difference Number:<p id="CharacterDifferenceNumber"></p>
Node Number Start: <p id="NodeNumberStart"></p>
Node Number End: <p id="NodeNumberEnd"></p>
Node Number: <p id="NodeNumber"></p>
```

As you can see from the "//" near the bottom, I have already tried some different ways from other questions on stackoverflow - I am sure I have tried everything and am missing something really simple :/
I have also taken out the "var" before setting things like PageName and NodeNumber after w3 said that this would then allow them to become global variables?

To give more information:

The code is based on TreeView - it has a tree with nodes on the left and you click on the nodes to open the page in the right hand frame. However clicking on a link from a page in the right page to a different page doesn't update the highlighting on the node and that is why I am trying to do this (onload).

EDIT: If possible I would also like to get the code into an external .js and reference it as I have multiple pages (I tried this for a few hours last week with different, working code, but also couldn't get this to work either).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
window.onload = function() {
    loadSynchPage(NodeNumber);
};
```

Or the onload in body tag, the problem you have is that it doesn't work in the sandbox in this snippet:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at
>   "http://stacksnippets.net" from accessing a frame at
>   "http://stackoverflow.com".  The frame requesting access is sandboxed
>   and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.

```js
function variables() {
//Getting the page's name from the URL
PageName = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
document.getElementById("PageName").innerHTML = PageName;

//Converting the page name into a string
PageNameString = String(PageName);
document.getElementById("PageNameString").innerHTML = PageNameString;

//Converting the string of the page name, into it's length
PageLength = PageNameString.length;
document.getElementById("PageLength").innerHTML = PageLength;

//Setting the DemoFramesetNodes.js as a variable (Copy and Paste in - needs to have no " and be on one line)
TextFromDemoFramesetNodesJS = "foldersTree = gFld(<i>Page 1 Title</i>, page1.htm)//000foldersTree.treeID = Framesetaux1 = insFld(foldersTree, gFld(Page 2 Title, page 2.htm)) //001insDoc(aux1, gLnk(R, Page 3 Title, Page3.htm)) //002aux1 = insFld(foldersTree, gFld(Page 4 Title, Page4.htm)) //003insDoc(aux1, gLnk(R, Page 5 Title, Page5.htm)) //004";
//Need to set the difference BETWEEN the "m" in htm and the start of the number
//e.g. page2.htm)) //001
CharacterDifference = "5";
document.getElementById("CharacterDifference").innerHTML = CharacterDifference;

//Need to find the location of the page's name from the DemoFramsetNodes
PageNameLocation = TextFromDemoFramesetNodesJS.lastIndexOf(PageNameString);
document.getElementById("PageNameLocation").innerHTML = PageNameLocation;

//Need to convert all variables to be added into numbers
PageNameLocationNumber = Number(PageNameLocation);
PageLengthNumber = Number(PageLength);
CharacterDifferenceNumber = Number(CharacterDifference);
document.getElementById("CharacterDifferenceNumber").innerHTML = CharacterDifferenceNumber;

//Add the variables to give us the start location of the Node Number
NodeNumberStart = PageNameLocationNumber + PageLengthNumber + CharacterDifferenceNumber;
document.getElementById("NodeNumberStart").innerHTML = NodeNumberStart;

//Add the variables to give us the end location of the Node Number
NodeNumberEnd = PageNameLocationNumber + PageLengthNumber + CharacterDifferenceNumber + 3;
document.getElementById("NodeNumberEnd").innerHTML = NodeNumberEnd;

//this gives us the Node Number that we want
NodeNumber = TextFromDemoFramesetNodesJS.substring(NodeNumberStart, NodeNumberEnd);
document.getElementById("NodeNumber").innerHTML = NodeNumber;

}
 var avar=Number(window.NodeNumber);

 //window.NodeNumber;

function loadSynchPage(linkID) {
  alert("loadSynchPage called");
  var folderObj;
  docObj = parent.treeframe.findObj(linkID);
  docObj.forceOpeningOfAncestorFolders();
  parent.treeframe.HightlightNode(linkID,docObj.link,'basefrm');
  if (typeof parent.treeframe.document.body != "undefined") // To handle scrolling not working with NS4
    parent.treeframe.document.body.scrollTop=docObj.navObj.offsetTop
}


loadSynchPage(NodeNumber);

//myvar=Number(NodeNumber);


// function loadnode(){
// document.getElementById('loadSynchPage').onclick=function(){loadSynchPage(myvar);};  

//   var myvar=15;
//function init(){
//    document.getElementById('EditBanner').onclick=function(){EditBanner(myvar);};
// }
```

```html
<button onclick="javascript:settingvariables();">Page Highlight1</button>
<button onclick="javascript:loadSynchPage(avar);">Page Highlight2</button>


Page Name: <p id="PageName"></p>
Page Name String: <p id="PageNameString"></p>
Page Length: <p id="PageLength"></p>
Character Difference: <p id="CharacterDifference"></p>
Page Name Location: <p id="PageNameLocation"></p>
Character Difference Number:<p id="CharacterDifferenceNumber"></p>
Node Number Start: <p id="NodeNumberStart"></p>
Node Number End: <p id="NodeNumberEnd"></p>
Node Number: <p id="NodeNumber"></p>
```

2nd question: Save all the script (not including the `<script>` tags) to myjs.js, put it to the same directory next to page.html, and remove the whole `<script>` block from html, and put this instead of it:

```
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've managed to get it working exactly as I wanted :D